# Fit data within two function bounds

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of data which, according to a theory, is bounded within two bounds.

The upper bound is : f(x)=1/x (x<0.5)

The lower bound is : f(x)=1+1/(2x)(x<0.5)

The data I got is close to one of these two bounds. I’m trying to find a function to describe these data. But if I use normal fitting method, the fitted curve can be outside of these two bounds. How can I force my fitted curve between these two bounds by using scipy.curve_fit? I'm trying to use Pade approximant to do the fitting, the code I'm using is following:

```
def pfuncp_3_1(x, a0, a1, a2, a3, b1):
    p1 = ((a0+a1*x+a2*x**2+a3*x**3)*(1+b1*x)**(-1)-1-1/(2*x)<0)*2.0
    p2 = ((a0+a1*x+a2*x**2+a3*x**3)*(1+b1*x)**(-1)-1/x>0)*2.0
    return (a0+a1*x+a2*x**2+a3*x**3)*(1+b1*x)**(-1) + p1 + p2


def ffuncp_3_1(x, a0, a1, a2, a3, b1):
    return (a0+a1*x+a2*x**2+a3*x**3)*(1+b1*x)**(-1)


def data_fitter(pfunc, ffunc, fit_x, fit_y, new_x):
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(pfunc, fit_x, fit_ny)
    perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
    interp_y = np.zeros(len(interp_x))
    for k in range(len(interp_x)):
        interp_y[k] = ffunc(interp_x[k], *popt)
    return interp_y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = data_fitter(pfunc, ffunc, original_x, original_y, interpx)
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: The code is added. I use the penalty function to do the fitting@JohnZwinck

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear: Is the data two dimensional, or is it from a one dimensional function? And what do you mean by implementing the bounds? Do you want to obtain them or do you want to find the function?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @AndreasStorvikStrauman the problem is rephrased

Comment: Aha! I think I get it now.

Comment: But you’re allowed to use the functions to specify the bound?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Yes, the bounds are two functions, not constants, which make the problem tricky to me

Comment: Are you sure that `x < 0.5` and not `x > 0.5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one needs to find a function that can be sent to `scipy.curve_fit`, with some parameters, that would be able to describe the functions we want, namely `1/x` and `1+1/(2x)`:
`h(x)=a+1/(b*x)`.

This will then give the upper and lower bounds for the parameters as follows:

`1/x` for `a=0`,`b=1`

and

`1+1/(2x)` for `a=1`, `b=2`

That means that `a` is in `[0,1]` and `b` is in `[1,2]`.

Now I'll be able to tell [`scipy.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that it has to choose the parameters `a`,`b` and `c` to stay within the bounds:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Generate data
a_true,b_true=.45,1.35
h=lambda x,a,b: a+1/(b*x)
N=100
xmin=0.1
xmax=0.499
x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,N)
y=h(x,a_true,b_true)+np.random.normal(0,0.05,N)
plt.plot(x,1/x,label="1/x")
plt.plot(x,1+1/(2*x), label="1+1/(2x)")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
# Do curve fit
popt, pcov =curve_fit(h,x,y,bounds=[(0,1),(1,2)])
print(popt)
plt.plot(x,1/x,label="1/x")
plt.plot(x,1+1/(2*x), label="1+1/(2x)")
plt.plot(x,h(x,*popt))
plt.show()
```